# How i turn this programme in selection sort

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;
class Example {
  public static void bubbleSort(int[] a) {
    for (int k=a.length-1; k>0; k--) {
      for (int i=0; ia[i+1]) {
        int temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[i+1];
        a[i+1]=temp;
      }
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
      try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
      } catch(Exception e){}
    }
  }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  int[] ar={98,78,56,34,23,58,21,67,37,8};
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));
  bubbleSort(ar);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to google, type "Java selection sort" and click any search result.
For example: http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/selection-sort/